Why doesnt this violate the galois correspondence? Which one is true?
I have been struggling with this specific confusion throughout my galois course, lets say we have like $x^{11}-42$. Then this will have degree 110, by adjoining $\zeta_{11}$ and $\sqrt[11](42)$.
We know that $Gal(Q(\zeta_{11})/Q)$ is isomorphic to $Z/10Z$, but  the Galois correspondence , says that a group of order should be 11 for this extension?
So basicly does the field extension of order 10 correspond to a group of order 11 or 10? And if it is 11, when why not 10?
Also $(Q(\zeta_{11})/Q)$ is a galois extension over the 11th cyclotomic polynomial.
Please helpp

That cyclotomic extension has degree 10, e.g. $x^{11}-1=(x-1)(x^{10}+...+1)$, so there is no problem.

Ok and does it correspond to a group of order 11?

Given a finite Galois extension $L/K$, the Galois correspondence realizes a bijection between the subextensions $M$ and the subgroups of $Gal(L/K)$. If a subgroup $H$ corresponds to a subextension $M$, then $H=Gal(L/M)$, so the degree of $M$ over $K$ is $\frac{[L:K]}{|H|}$!

Oh ok thank you , it makes sense now, but so if L/K has degree 110, M is a field extension of degree 10 over K, then it corresponds to Gal(L/M) with degree 11?

Captain Lama's answer and Aphelli's comment explain this specific problem very well. This old thread discusses a natural follow up -question of figuring out what that Galois group of order $110$ looks like. My answer is mostly about book keeping, but Tom Oldfield's answer ties the question to a very concrete group. Caveat, you may need two more weeks of lectures to be able to follow the arguments. Have fun!

I'm not sure that is what you mean, but $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})/\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed a Galois extension of degree 10, so there is no contradiction that its Galois group has order 10.
The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{11}$ is $X^{10}+X^9+\dots+X+1$, which is of degree 10.

Yes but then the galois theorem sas if we have :                                                                              L             ${1}$                                                                                                                                   K              H                                                                                                                                          Q              G    ,           and L/K is galois , then like the extension K/Q is [G:H] , and in my case its 10, and G has order 110, so H has order 11, not 10.

I think what makes you confused is that you think that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})/\mathbb{Q}$ is the subgroup of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ that appears in the Galois correspondance, but this is not the case: the subgroup in question is $H = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})$, which has order 11, and $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{11})/\mathbb{Q}$ is the quotient of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ by $H$.
